# What is the proper way to convert Iterator to Iterable in Scala 2.13?

Tags: scala, iterator, scala-2.13

When upgrading the scala version of an existing code base the build warns that the `.toIterable` method on an `Iterator` is deprecated.

**How can an Iterator be converted to an Iterable in Scala 2.13?**

Intellij recommends

> use `.iterator.to(Iterable)`

However, the `.iterator` seems redundant.

Thank you in advance for your consideration and response.

Comment: Are you sure you want any arbitrary iterable? That may change order, lose elements, have extremely bad performance for the following operations, etc; I would pick a concrete collection like `toList`, but if you are ok with whatever you can just call `to(Iterable)`

Comment: maybe try reading that warning to the end? ;)

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez `.toList` is also deprecated :)

Comment: @Dima ahm no, it isn't: https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Iterator.html#toList:List[A] there is an overload version that is deprecated tho.

Comment: @dima Luis is correct. He meant using `to(Iterable)` directly without calling `.iterator`. Also I recommend just use `toList` directly because `Iterable`'s factory is just a delegate of List so `to(Iterable)` will give you a List anyway: https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.13.5/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/Iterable.scala#L32

Comment: @texasbruce yeah, I dunno. Intelling me `toList` is deprecated to and suggests `to(List)`, which kinda makes sense. It looks like there's really two of them (which is another reason not to use it if you ask me) ... In any event, I think using `toList` or `to(List)` when you just need an iterable, is a bad practice in the first place: one should always be using the most abstract interface that fits the need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally,

```scala
   val v: Iterator[Int] = ???
   val vv = v.to(Iterable)
```

but if you need more than one iteration

```scala
   val v: Iterator[Int] = ???
   val vv: Iterable[Int] = v.to(List)
```